# How can i add cross hairs over a map image

Tags: javascript, html, mapping, location, coordinates

I'm wanting to have a user type in a place and display a zone to the right along with red cross hairs floating over the map to the left for the user to see where it is on the map, I've gotten everything working except for how to add cross hairs. Found below is an example of what I'm working with

```
<div class"main">
    <div class="map">
      <img src="../IMG/snowload.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="lookup">
      <h1>SNOW LOAD</h1>
      <label for="city-input">Enter Place:</label>
      <input type="text" id="city-input" placeholder="e.g., city">
      <button onclick="lookupSnowLoadGroup()">Lookup</button>
      <p id="result"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```
function lookupSnowLoadGroup() {
  var cityInput = document.getElementById('city-input').value;
  var snowLoadGroup = getSnowLoadGroup(cityInput);
  document.getElementById('result').textContent = snowLoadGroup;
}

function getSnowLoadGroup(city) {
  // Replace this sample data with your actual snow load group data
  var snowLoadGroups = {
    "albert": "B",
    "alexander": "A",
  };

  var trimmedCity = city.trim();
  return snowLoadGroups[trimmedCity] || "Not Found";
}
```